# How to open multiple pics on single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made four buttons with single bootstrap modal & a button in bootstrap modal to open pic according to click on four buttons.

Now single bootstrap modal is open on each button click & one button inside modal ("Open Document") I want to work on that like...

If anyone open modal through Open Modal2 then on click "open document" should be open pic as per modal 2

I'm unable to do this anyone can do it?

```css
.buttons{ margin:20px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Moda2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Moda3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Moda4</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<button class="btn btn-success" onClick="window.open('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdR1m.jpg','_self')">Open Document</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdR1m.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is your Solution mate :**

```js
$(".modelButton").click(function(){
  $(".modelDocButton").attr("href",$(this).data("href"));
});
```

```css
.buttons{ margin:20px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modelButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdR1m.jpg">Open Modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modelButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-href="https://i.imgur.com/3TWgv.jpg">Open Moda2</button>

    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    <a class="btn btn-success modelDocButton" href="#">Open Document</a>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">         
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="window.open('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdR1m.jpg','_self')">Open Document</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```